# Can the Mystery Watcher still be found?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I have played through the main storyline of Arkham City, and somewhere along the course of the game I missed the mission for the Mystery Watcher.  According to this [website](http://www.videogamesblogger.com/2011/10/18/batman-arkham-city-achievements-trophies-guide-xbox-360-ps3.htm), he still spawns after the main missions are over, but is that really the case, and if so, does anyone know where I need to go to find him?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is [all you need to know about the mystery watcher](http://www.gamesradar.com/batman-arkham-city-watcher-wings-side-mission-guide/)

Location 1:
[image]

Location 2:
[image]

Location 3:
[image]

Location 4:
[image]

Once you have all 4 sigils:

> Scanning the fourth symbol that the watcher leaves behind will automatically take you to the Batcomputer screen. Use the right and left sticks to rotate and move the sigil so that its four points match the four locations in which you spotted the watcher. Doing so reveals the watchers final location: the eastern side of the church. Scan the symbol on the wall there to complete this side mission.

Final location:

[image]

Comment: Note that after you find him, you might need to exit/reload your game in order to get him to spawn at the next location.

Comment: @Adeese This applies I assume only to the free roam mode? When I played the game myself he appeared multiple times in the same session after certain missions

Comment: @JohnoBoy Yes, if you find him after finishing the main quest he might not reappear without reloading. I remember reading that somewhere, but unfortunately I can't remember where.