# In Arkham City, how do you interact with Azrael?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the Mystery Watcher still be found?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46528/can-the-mystery-watcher-still-be-found)

In Arkham City I know that Azrael appears in the game as a side quest. I have compelted the game and have not found anything that could lead to me being able to initiate that quest or interact with Azrael.

How can I find Azrael and complete the related quest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can meet Azrael for the first time after rescuing Catwoman right at the beginning of the game. He is present on top of a building right in front of the courthouse. Interacting with him will cause him to disappear, leaving behind a symbol on the ground. Scan it with your detective mission to begin the side quest 'The Mysterious Watcher'.

> He can be found in three other locations all around Arkham City and he will leave behind symbols for you to scan. Scanning all symbols and solving a puzzle will lead you to his final location. Meet with him there to complete the quest.

[GUIDE](http://www.gamesradar.com/batman-arkham-city-watcher-wings-side-mission-guide/)

Comment: Additionally you will get the "Catch" achievement if you throw your remote controlled batarang at him from a distance.

Answer (score 1):

While gliding around the city, you may find him.  Keep detective vision on, and look for a blue figure that is just standing, not patrolling.

> Across from courthouse, on top of ferris wheel, and outside of riddlers church are good places to look.